# how can we do to get different types(like the model for view does not need the all fields) in EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

In NHibernate, we can use setResultTransformer to get different types.

```
query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(ViewAd.class));
```

However, what can we do to get different types(like the model for view does not need the all fields of a table) **in EntityFramework**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .AsParallel().OfType<DenemeClass>().ToList();   ????

Answer (score 0):

Try [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).  It allows you to define and use mappings:

Define in Global.asax.cs:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>();
```

Use the map in your code:

```
OrderDto dto = Mapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);
```